# apache config for auto domain directory

Tags: apache-2.2

I edit /etc/hosts file to add domains. I add new virtual host for new domain.
So I can easily develop.

What I want now is to have apache conf to

1. if there is a virtualhost domain definition follow
2. if not, look for /var/www directory, if there is dir follow
3. if there is not, redirect to /var/www/nerkn

Can apache conf make it?

1)Example domain example.com

1. there is no example.com in virtualhost
2. there is a directory named /var/www/example.com so server there

2)Exampple domain ex2.com

1. there is no ex2.com in virtualhost
2. there is no directory named /var/www/ex2.com
3. serve from /var/www/nerkn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_vhost_alias, where nerkn defined as default virthost

```
VirtualDocumentRoot d:/Sites/%0/web
VirtualScriptAlias d:/Sites/%0/cgi-bin
```

define base location of bare minimum (my config)

while adding `<VirtualHost dcweb.e-city.net.ru:80>` allow redegine-add vhost-specific details

Comment: it only solves 2nd bu its ok. Thank you

Comment: it **work most times** for me in 1st mode - I just copy skeleton to the new site-location and have site ready without restart of apache

Comment: wonderful **ln -s nerkn new-site**